# Samsung sms in call log, how can I delete it?

Tags: android, sms, logging

With the new Android 2.2+ operating systems deployed on Samsung phones, the call log has been replaced with a special super log. The super log contains also the information about sent sms. How I can delete this type of log? Can I use a particular Uri (content://...) to delete it? I read that Samsung uses the LogsProvider.apk to manage logs, is there the open source code of it?

Thanks.
Denis.

Comment: Have the same issue now. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the calls using this:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null);
```

I don't think `**LogsProvider**` app Samsung is open source.

Comment: Hi, I think that context.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null) works on standard Android but not in Samsung personalization. I'm saying something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Uri to be used for deleting Samsung log is "content://logs/historys".

Use this Uri to delete all the sms log of a particular number.

String smsLogUri = "content://logs/historys";

Context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(smsLogUri), " logtype = 300 and number like ?", new String[]{phoneNumber});

logtype= 300 is used to delete only sms log.
If you want to delete sms log of all numbers then use:

Context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(smsLogUri), " logtype = 300 ", null);

Comment: It requires your app to have android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL which is a signature level permission. Which is not something you can achieve unless you either are the creator or the system build, or collaborating with them such that they are willing to sign your apk with their certificate. In other words, this is off limits for most developers.