# SMS are duplicated as Calls(Samsung galaxy S II)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, samsung-mobile

Ok, guys, here's my code for getting SMS:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " > " + lastSmsTime, null,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + " ASC");
```

Where type is:

```
"content://sms/inbox"
"content://sms/sent"
```

And for calls:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.DATE };
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + " > " + lastCallTime, null,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + " ASC");
```

First of all, I know that this is undocumented provider(as you see, I use column constants from different one).

Funny thing is that this is working ok on several 2.3.x devices. But now I tried this on Galaxy S II(ICS 4.0.3). Now all SMS *are duplicated* in calls provider.

Has anyone come across this issue?

**UPD**
I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157983/samsung-sms-in-call-log-how-can-i-delete-it), keep looking for the solution.

**UDD 2** from what I know now, Samsung now stores everything in one log, so I'll try to find a way to reverse-engineer log application.

Anyway, still looking for solution to **separate sms and calls**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's might be the solution, so I'm posting it:
Samsung logs provider has lot's of columns, among them is

```
logtype
```

which, as far as I see, for calls is 100, for SMS is 300 and for MMS is 200.

It's also possible to detect manufacturer:

> String man = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

So, for samsung devices there should be separate code which will check the *logtype*.

Answer (score 0):

Just been looking at this myself. A more generic solution is to eliminate all incoming call entries with a duration of 0.

Comment: what about missed calls? they have a duration of 0. Perhaps checking the type as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor query = this.managedQuery(
        CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " in ('3','5') OR " + CallLog.Calls.DURATION + ">0 ", null, null);
//Calls.Type is 3 for Missed Calls and 5 for Cancelled Calls and **Calls.Duration** is 0 for Message, Missed Calls and Cancelled Calls
```

This code worked fine for me. I had went to 3-4 other links but all of them suggested to delete the Log of Message from CallLog. This is probably the only way to get only Voice Call Logs by not writing/deleting from any log