# What is logtype=100 OR logtype=500?

Tags: android

When I use `ContentResolver.query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, Calls._ID = 'call ID here', null,null);` the text `(logtype=100 OR logtype=500)` is added to the query.

what do 100 and 500 mean ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445430/samsung-device-returns-text-messages-when-querying-for-call-log

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have a Samsung Android device. Look here:
100 is for voice calls.
[SMS are duplicated as Calls(Samsung galaxy S II)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294563/sms-are-duplicated-as-callssamsung-galaxy-s-ii)