# Samsung device returns text messages when querying for call-log

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, samsung-mobile, calllog

Some of my users report that on their Samsung devices (GT-N7000 & SGH-I777) a query I make in my app for the [CallLog.Calls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) displays also text messages.

I've created a dump of their `CallLog` `ContentProvider`, and it seems to have extra fields not mentioned in the Android API, and not returned on any of our test devices.

Specifically, looking through the dump, there's a field called `logtype`, which seems to equal 100 for calls, and 300 for text messages.
Having searching online for this field, I didn't find any official documentation for this field's values, but I came across lots of other possible values for this field mainly via crash stack traces, which reveal underlining queries by the `ContentProvider`:

> logtype=300 OR logtype=200
>
> logtype=100 OR logtype=500 OR logtype=800 OR logtype=900 OR
>   logtype=1000

So I assume that 300/200 are used for text messages, and 100/500/800/900/1000 are used for calls, but I'm not sure, since I haven't seen 500/800/900/1000 being used on the reporting users' devices.

Can someone shed some light for the possible values of logtype, and their meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to tentatively solve it by querying `CallLog.Calls` for the column `logtype`, if an exception is thrown, I query normally, otherwise, I query with selection of `(logtype=100 OR logtype=500)`

This seems to be working for my reporting users, but I'm still not sure if it covers all bases, since there are many possible values for `logtype` for which I don't know the meaning.

If anyone has a better answer, please add it.

Comment: can you specify what logtype=100 is vs logtype=500? i've got a conversation going with samsung over this issue. It's extremely frustrating without access to the device.

Comment: Hey, I actually don't know, I've googled the field name 'logtype' at the time, and found some crash logs from devices suggesting that the stock call-log filters on 100 and 500:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
near ")": syntax error: , while compiling: 
SELECT _id, name, number, type FROM logs WHERE (logtype=100 OR logtype=500) AND (_ID=) 
So I've added it to my query with fingers crossed... so far so good.
Totally with you on the frustrating feeling

Answer (score 2):

Hello If you will check callLog.Calls columns you will find messageid field which says that this is message for samsung phones.
So if you just want to get the list of calls without messages simply do :

int messageIdIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex("messageid");

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{

```
if(messageIdIndex>=0)
    messageID=cursor.getLong(messageIdIndex);

if(messageID<=0)
{
    //do whatever you need with calls log data
}
```

}

cursor.close();

Answer (score 0):

When i was debugging a sgs2 device i have found this. may be useful for someone.

```
SELECT number, name, type, date, duration FROM logs WHERE (
logs.logtype=100 OR 
logs.logtype=110 OR 
logs.logtype=900 OR 
logs.logtype=500 OR 
logs.logtype=800 OR 
logs.logtype=120 OR 
logs.logtype=510 OR 
logs.logtype=1000 OR 
(logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logs.logtype=300) 
AND ((type != 4)) AND (logtype=100 OR logtype=500))) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, we have found Samsung devices using the value *1150*, *100* or *1000* for the 'logtype' field in the Calls content provider.

I cannot confirm if any of the other values mentioned here are used.