# Call logs wih sms logs at the same place in android vesion - 4.0.4

Tags: java, android

I am creating application which reads call logs in this way:

```
 Uri uriCallsURI = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
 Cursor cur = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(uriCallsURI, null, null, null, "_id");
```

Everything is working with android 2.3.6, but android 4.0.4 also displays SMS as call log.
How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: probably some definition or API changed. I've written my answer below, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yushulx, problem was elsewhere. Samsung has column logtype in call logs. I found an answer at 
[Samsung device returns text messages when querying for call-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445430/samsung-device-returns-text-messages-when-querying-for-call-log)

I have modified your code, now I get only call logs on samsung phone with android 4.0.4.

```
Cursor cur = null;
try {

    cur = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, 
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,  CallLog.Calls.NEW},
            "logtype=100 OR logtype=500", null, "_id");

    displayLogs(cur);

} catch(SQLiteException e){

    cur = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, 
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,  CallLog.Calls.NEW},
            null, null, "_id");

     displayLogs(cur);

} finally {
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard code string. Try to write code like this:

```
Cursor cur = null;
        try {
            cur = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER },
                    null, null, "_id");

            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Log.i("call", "id = " + cur.getString(0));
                    Log.i("call", "number = " + cur.getString(1));
                    Log.i("call", "..................................");
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null) {
                cur.close();
            }
        }
```