# How to remove SMS logs programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to remove all the logs on the device through this code:

```
 contentResolver.delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null);
```

But it only deletes Call Logs, and SMS logs still remain undeleted.
How delete all the logs including SMS logs? 
Any help would be appreciated..!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting Android SMS programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically)

Comment: May Helpful For u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically

Comment: If I was using your program and I would have realized that you are tampering with my SMS log (I can imagine no application which should read my SMS') I would grab a rotary hoe and tousle your dog with it. Are you sure you want to have a mob of angry users ready to lynch you? No offense this was just theorycrafting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246478/cant-remove-sms-logs-from-call-log-on-samsung-devices
this is what i am asking!

Comment: @ashu check it out my answer work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
getContext().getContentResolver().delete(
    Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + threadID), 
    null, 
    null);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **all smslog** using this way.

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),null,null);
```

for Deleting SMS from your smslog need uses permission declared in your **manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: I have already received a write solution to this by offering some bounty here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246478/cant-remove-sms-logs-from-call-log-on-samsung-devices

Comment: please then post your answer.for New Stack overflow user.